# What is the "user was removed" +2 achievement?

Tags: support, users

Just saw this:

[image: +2 user was removed]

What is the achievement, and who was the removed user?

Just learning how this website works, thanks

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it). If you have questions about why some system thing happened, you're usually better off on **the** Meta, not *a* meta.

Answer (score 8):

A user downvoted your post, and you lost 2 rep. The user account was later deleted (for reasons we don't know), so any votes they cast on your posts were reversed, hence the refund of 2 rep.

Votes (up/down) are anonymous, so we cannot know who the user was.

Read more on [MSE FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/309993).